# Tkinter: inverting what text has a tag in a range of two indexes

Tags: python, tags, tkinter

How do I create a method that given two indexes it will remove a specified tag from the text that has it and add that tag to the text that does not have it (only within the specified range)?

Comment: "For no apparent reason" doesn't mean there's not a reason. Tkinter is quite solid and deterministic; if you were getting an infinite loop you were doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I knew there was probably a reason for it. I didn't mean to indicate that there wasn't. I just didn't understand what the reason for it was (it didn't seem apparent). Anyway, I edited that part out of the question. And I do agree about Tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working method:

```
def invert_tag(self, start, end=None, tag=SEL, w=None):
    if w==None:
        w=self.cur_scroll() #This is my current text widget
    i=0
    while w.compare(start+"+"+str(i)+"c", "<", end):
        if "sel" in w.tag_names(start+"+"+str(i)+"c"):
            w.tag_remove(tag, start+"+"+str(i)+"c")
        else:
            w.tag_add(tag, start+"+"+str(i)+"c")
        i+=1
```

Comment: What is the problem with using INSERT in a loop? Your explanation is hard to understand.

Comment: I don't remember. I think I'll just remove the INSERT comment from my question and answer, since it's not essential to the problem, and I don't really remember what the issue was without programming the stuff I deleted before I asked this question again. I think I meant wordstart/wordend instead of or in addition INSERT. I may go over that code again in future and let you know when I do, but I don't have time atm.

Comment: I'm not saying that the difficulty of using it in a loop was caused by a problem with Tkinter, but rather by my misunderstanding of some things about how to use the built-in marks correctly in loops. For instance (this is abstract from my question), you have to consider that at the beginning of an empty document INSERT is "\n" instead of nothing. Also, changing position to insert wordstart doesn't go anywhere when you're on whitespace (it's logical, but sometimes not what initially makes sense to the uneducated). Stuff like that.